# Equivalent AES encryption code in c# .net core

Tags: c#, c, .net-core, openssl, cryptography

I have a AES/CBC encryption code written in C. I have to convert this code in C#

**C Code:**

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&e_ctx);
err = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&e_ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, NULL);   
err = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&e_ctx,EVP_CIPH_NO_PADDING);    
err = EVP_EncryptUpdate(&e_ctx,cipher,&cipher_len,plain,plain_len); 
err = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&e_ctx, cipher+cipher_len, &f_len);
```

**C# code:**

```
  using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aesAlg.Key = key; 
                    //aesAlg.IV = IV; 
                    // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                     ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(); 
                    // Create the streams used for encryption.
                    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) 
                    { using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) 
                        { using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) 
                            { 
                                //Write all data to the stream.
                                swEncrypt.Write(data); 
                            } 
                            byte[] encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray(); 
                        } 
                    } 
                }
```

But in both the case I am getting different ciphertext. While the key was the same.
While IV is not used in C code. So not using in c# code as well. But I doubt there is some default IV used by the OpenSSL and .net API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AES-256-CBC in .NET Core (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555145/aes-256-cbc-in-net-core-c)

Comment: You need to set the mode to CBC and padding to None as the C code does.

Comment: none padding will not work. will return error like input data must be in block size

Comment: There is a public and private key.  The public key is sent with data.  If you are sending serial data the public key is sometimes the beginning of the message.

Comment: @jdweng This is about AES, AES only has a single secret key. Please don't confuse matters.

Comment: How about proving a full sample dataset (plaintext, key, initialization vector [maybe it's internally generated by C-code...] and resulting ciphertext? That may help us in finding a solution. Btw: the C-code is "EVP_CIPH_NO_PADDING" which means "no padding". It would the best to show a full running (even with errors) c#-example where we can see your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C and C# code differ *only* in the IV. In the C code, `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` passes a `NULL` as 5th parameter, which results in a zero IV, i.e. an IV consisting only of `0x00` values. In contrast, the C# code uses a random IV created when `Aes.Create()` is called.

The C# code is therefore functionally identical to the C code if a zero vector is applied in the C# code. To do this, add below the line `aesAlg.Key = key`:

```
aesAlg.IV = new byte[16];
```

Apart from that, both codes use the *same* mode and the *same* padding:

- Mode: In the C code, `EVP_aes_256_cbc()` explicitly sets the CBC mode, which is the *default* mode in the C# code.
- Padding: In the C code, padding is only *ostensibly* disabled. [`EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding.html) disables the default PKCS7 padding only if the 2nd parameter is `0`. But the latter is not the case, because `EVP_CIPH_NO_PADDING` is defined as `0x100`. So the C code uses the default PKCS7 padding, which is the *default* padding in the C# code.
  It is possible that the padding not being disabled in the C code is an oversight caused by the accidental use of `EVP_CIPH_NO_PADDING` in the context of `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()`. According to the documentation, `EVP_CIPH_NO_PADDING` is applied in the context of [`EVP_CIPHER_meth_set_flags()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_CIPHER_meth_free.html).

If the above line is added so that a zero vector is used in the C# code, the C and C# code produce the same ciphertext for identical input data on my machine.

Note, however, that a static IV, like a zero IV, is insecure. Usually a random IV is generated for each encryption, which, since it is not secret, is sent along with the ciphertext (typically concatenated).

Comment: Thanks!!! To Set the IV zero..produced the same result.